# Twilio Flex Plugin - Invoke Action On Click

Tags: typescript, twilio, twilio-flex

In a Twilio Flex plugin, I want to have a button next to `Reject` that sends the call back to the IVR flow (where they'll be prompted to leave a voicemail).

[image]

I can get this to work via the `Reject` button if I replace the `RejectTask` action:

```js
flex.Actions.replaceAction('RejectTask', async (payload, original) => {

    const url: string = payload.task.attributes.transferToIvrUrl;
    const CallSid: string = payload.task.attributes.call_sid;
    const reservationSid = payload.sid;
    const transferToIVRMenu = 'vm';

    if (!url || !CallSid) {
        await original(payload);
        return;
    }

    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.accept();
    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.wrap();
    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.complete();
    await request(url, { CallSid, transferToIVRMenu });
});
```

However, I don't want to replace the `RejectTask` action. I would like to invoke the body of the function above when the `SendToVm` button is clicked, whether that's by invoking an action or some other means.

Here's my current attempt.

The button:

```js
flex.DefaultTaskChannels.Call.addedComponents = [{
    target: "TaskListButtons",
    component: <Flex.IconButton onClick={sendToVmButtonClick()} key="vm-button" icon="Voice" />
}];
```

Button click method:

```js
const sendToVmButtonClick = () => async () => {
    await flex.Actions.invokeAction("SendToVmTask");
};
```

The action:

```js
flex.Actions.registerAction('SendToVmTask', async (payload) => {

    const url: string = payload.task.attributes.transferToIvrUrl;
    const CallSid: string = payload.task.attributes.call_sid;
    const reservationSid = payload.sid;
    const transferToIVRMenu = 'vm';

    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.accept();
    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.wrap();
    await manager.workerClient.reservations.get(reservationSid)?.complete();
    await request(url, { CallSid, transferToIVRMenu });
});
```

The problem is, the way I'm calling that action now, `payload` is undefined, so the function doesn't have access to any of those values that it needs. I'm not sure how to provide the task to the function when it's invoked.

Any help would be appreciated. I apologize for my ignorance. I haven't worked much with React or Twilio plugin development.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is include the task context in the component that you are adding to the page, so that you can send it as the payload to the action. I think you will need to wrap the `<Flex.IconButton>` in your own component in order to do this.

Using the `withTaskContext` function to wrap the component will mean that the component is created with a `task` property. You can then use that in the `payload` you send when you invoke the Action.

Something like this should work:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withTaskContext } from "@twilio/flex-ui";

class SendToVMButton extends Component {
  const sendToVmButtonClick = async () => {
    await flex.Actions.invokeAction("SendToVmTask", { task: props.task }); 
  };

  render() {
    return <Flex.IconButton onClick={sendToVmButtonClick} key="vm-button" icon="Voice" />
  }
}

export default withTaskContext(SendToVMButton);
```

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I got that pretty close to working, but running into some compile-time errors. I actually changed something in at different point in my call center setup, where I don't need this anymore. However, I'll probably come back to this later. So, thanks again for your help.

Comment: The important thing here is that if you need data on the current task, `withTaskContext` is your friend. You may need to check for the presence of the task though. Good luck with it!